# Conda: how to include pytest tests in meta.yml?

Tags: anaconda, conda

I built the `sdist` of `mypackage` and the content of the generated `tar.gz` file is as follows:

```
.
├── LICENSE
├── pyproject.toml
├── README.md
├── PKG-INFO
├── src
└── tests
```

Section test of `meta.yml` is as it follows

```
test:
  imports:
    - mypackage
  commands:
    - pip check
    - pytest --pyargs mypackage
  requires:
    - pip
    - pytest
```

However, the output of `conda build` related to `pytest` execution is the following:

```
============================= test session starts ==============================
platform darwin -- Python 3.11.3, pytest-7.3.1, pluggy-1.0.0
rootdir: $SRC_DIR
collected 0 items

============================ no tests ran in 0.00s =============================
```

i.e. no test ran whereas it should have run about 300 tests.

Local execution of `pytest ./tests/` work fine.
Replacing `pytest --pyargs mypackage` with `pytest ./tests/` in the `meta.yml` returns `ERROR: file or directory not found: ./tests/` when attempting to execute tests with `pytest`.

I also tried to include under `test` the following

source_files:
- src/
files:
- tests/

But the mentioned problems(s) still remain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLUTION**

```
test:
  source_files:
    - src/
    - tests/
  imports:
    - mypackage
  commands:
    - pip check
    - pytest ./tests
  requires:
    - pip
    - pytest
```